# Is it possible to call a batch file while compiling an Inno Setup script?

Tags: compilation, inno-setup

I'd like to call a batch file at the start of an Inno Setup compile process. i.e. before it starts compiling, perform an external operation. Is this possible or should my external activity be wrapping the Inno Setup compile process?

Comment: I've just updated the title to make it explicit where you want it to run. Compile time and run time are VERY different.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have ISPP installed with Inno (It's built in now) then you can use the [`Exec()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec) preprocessor function to run your batch file. The compile will be paused until it returns (place it at the beginning of your file).

```
#expr Exec("c:\file.bat")
```

If your command takes arguments, you have to write it as:

```
#expr Exec('c:\my_cmd.exe','some_argument')
```

You can also run it from a batch file that then calls the setup compiler.

Comment: +1, never seen this before and overlooked that in source code. Nice to learn something new!

Comment: And thanks for the link, I forgot the ISPP help was separate :)

Comment: my batch file is not getting executed..

expr Exec("file.bat")

Comment: Needed this, really helped!

Comment: I can't actually find this in the docs! EDIT: Oh, you actually linked to it. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

*As an addendum to the accepted answer, here is the documentation for [Exec()](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec) in case the help pages ever go down.*

**Inno Setup Preprocessor: Exec**

**Prototype**
int Exec(str 1, str? 2, str? 3, int? 4, int? 5)

**Description**
Executes specified executable file.

First argument specifies the filename of the module to execute.

Second argument may be used to specify command line to execute.

Third argument may be used to specify the working directory of the process.

Fourth argument should be set to zero, if you don't wish to wait for the process to finish, and non-zero otherwise. By default, non-zero value is assumed.

Fifth argument can be any of the SW_* constants defined in ISPPBuiltins.iss file. For GUI processes, it specifies the default value the first time ShowWindow is called. By default, SW_SHOWNORMAL (i. e. 1) is assumed.

If fourth argument is omitted or is non-zero, the function returns the exit code of the process. Otherwise, the function result indicates whether the process has been successfully launched (non-zero for success).