# Inno Setup Pre- / Post- compile action

Tags: windows, inno-setup

Is it possible to define pre-/post-compile actions in `*.iss` script?

In short I need to run `*.bat` script before compilation and after.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to revert your logic and run command-line compiler from the batch file:

```
call precompile.bat

ISCC.exe setup.iss

call postcompile.bat
```

---

If you need a GUI solution, there's [ISTool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/), an Inno Setup extension, that has direct support for Pre Compilation and Post Compilation "Steps". But this project is unfortunately no longer maintained. You might be able to update it to the latest Inno Setup version, as it is open source.

---

Another way to run some script before compilation is using [`Exec` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec).

```
#expr Exec("precompile.bat")
```

See also [Is it possible to call a batch file while compiling an Inno Setup script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10513398/850848)

Comment: make sure that the Inno Setup folder is on PATH

Answer (score -5):

@Martin Prikryl, @CODIJY:

ISTool is really old and deprecated. Does anyone still use it?

There are also advanced GUI tools like **Visual & Installer** (for Microsoft Visual Studio) or **RAD & Installer** (for Embarcadero RAD Studio - a little self promo :)

In these modern tools you can easily specify "Launch tool after build" and "Launch tool before build" events and run your .bat file.

[image: Project Properties]