# Run a [Code] or PowerShell script in Inno Setup compiler

Tags: powershell, inno-setup, pascalscript

Is there a way to run a `[Code]` procedure or PowerShell script in the Inno Setup compiler before the installation executable is generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You may get better answers, if you explain what you need to run the code for. Anyway...*

---

One way is to [compile the script on command-line](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline) from a batch file:

```
powershell -file precompile.ps1

ISCC.exe setup.iss

powershell -file postcompile.ps1
```

(or you can call `ISCC.exe` from the PowerShell script itself)

---

Another way to run some script before compilation is using [`Exec` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec).

```
#expr Exec("precompile.bat")
```

or

```
#expr Exec("powershell -file precompile.ps1")
```

See also [Is it possible to call a batch file while compiling an Inno Setup script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10513398/850848)

---

If you need a GUI solution, there's [ISTool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/), an Inno Setup extension, that has direct support for Pre Compilation and Post Compilation "Steps". But this project is unfortunately no longer maintained. You might be able to update it to the latest Inno Setup version, as it is open source.