# Multiple output directories

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to use as an output directory not only one location?

Something like this:

```
[Setup]
OutputDir=C:\MyProject; C:\Installers
```

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, the same installer is used by 2 similar projects. It's not really necessary, I was just wondering, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.

---

If you are compiling the installer as a part of a larger build process, you can clone the output files as part of that.

See also:
[Run a [Code] or PowerShell script in Inno Setup compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48772183/850848)

---

One possible hack would be to execute some script in the background using preprocessor (as shown in the answer to the question above). And have the script watch for changes to the output file and copy it over to the other destination.

Comment: Thanks, it's also a great solution!